# Java HttpServletRequest: Wait with repsonse

Tags: java, ajax, jakarta-ee, servlets

maybe the question is a little misleading, but I will explain what I need:

1. If have a Servlet which is called via ajax / POST. The Servlet will get an instance of a COM port reader,opens the COM port and send a character to the port. So far so good.
2. The 'port reader' has an event listener and waits for data coming in from the port and if data is available it will return this data.

What I want to do is waiting with the response in the doPost of the servlet until data will arrive and send this data as a response to the client.

Are there any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Servlet 3.0 adds support for asynchronous processing in Servlets. Search for that.

Answer (score 1):

Servlet 3.0 has [asynchronous support in servlets](https://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/asynchronous_support_in_servlet_3). This way you can do long-running tasks inside your Servlet.

However, make sure that the request of your browser made to the server is kept open until the response is sent to the client.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't  try to wait in a servlet for some data until it is available and then send it back.

You have to recall that servlets are executet in an own thread which the server provides from a thread pool it manages. So imagin if a lot of clients send this `POST` request in nearly the same times and your servlet starts wating, you may then run out of threads for your application.

I would let the `POST` request return immediately and have another ajax `GET` request which polls the servlet to get the data. You could use javascript's [setInterval()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to implement the polling.

Comment: That's exactly the reason why the Servlet 3.0 specification added support for asynchronous processing in Servlets: To support long-running tasks in servlet without running out of threads.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is only one client. The reason why I don't think about asynch requests is that the hardware communicate with this app through the comport and only sends data if the client requests it. The client must wait for this particular answer and sends additional requests to the serial port depending on the hardwares answer. Every time the client / servlet must wait for exactly this one answer and then commit and close the request. That's the reason why I thionk about a kind of event listener. My solution for this moment is to run in a while loop unitl the com port answers.